# Triggers - How to change another column when one is updated - MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have been given a use case where an user needs to update a certain `TIME` field if other of the same type changes.

I have been given two columns

**horario_arribo (TIME)**

**horario_salida (TIME)**

Now, what I need to do is the followin

Make a trigger so when I change for example **horario_arribo**, **horario_salida** is the same TIME as **horario_arribo** minus 1 hour, and the same if I update **horario_salida** , make **horario_arribo** plus 1 hour.

I have been thinking how to do it, first check if the value trying to be updated is **horario_salida**, then I just add 1 hour to **horario_arribo**, or if  I'm updating **horario_arribo**, to the same to **horario_salida** but minus 1 hour.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER modificar_horarioruta AFTER
UPDATE ON ruta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(new.horario_salida) THEN
  SET AddTime(old.horario_arribo, '00:60:00')
ELSE
  SET AddTime(old.horario_salida, Here I dont know how to minus 1 hour to that)
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the data I have

[image]

So , in short, if I update **horario_salida**, **horario_arribo** need to be 1 hour ahead, if I update **horario_arribo**, **horario_salida** needs to be 1 hour less.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER modificar_horarioruta AFTER
UPDATE ON ruta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.horario_salida) THEN
  SET NEW.horario_arribo = OLD.horario_arribo + 1;
ELSE
  SET NEW.horario_salida = OLD.horario_salida - 1;
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Let me know if this is not what you need.